# <article> não aparece depois do CSS

Tags: css

Criei um gráfico no CSS que funciona bem, mas ao tentar posicioná-lo na página com CSS ele some.

O CSS é esse:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");

    /*Aqui começa o Gráfico */
    $pqtv = 0.75;
    $qtv = $pqtv * 100;
    $grau = $pqtv * 180;
    //linear gradient
    $corlinear = "orange";
    $corlinearHEX = "102, 102, 102,";
    $cordafonte = "orange";
    $cordefundo = "#fff";
        ?>

    .quantidades {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      transform: rotate(<?php echo $grau ?>deg);
         background: linear-gradient(0deg, <?php echo $corlinear; ?> 50%, rgba(<?php echo $corlinearHEX; ?> 0.2) 50%); }
      .quantidades, .quantidades:before, .quantidades:after {
        width: 12rem;
        height: 12rem;
        border-radius: 50%; }
      .quantidades:before, .quantidades:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: <?php echo $cordafonte; ?>;
        text-align: center; }
      .quantidades:before {
        content: "QTDES";
        width: 12rem;
        height: 12rem;
        background: <?php echo $cordefundo; ?> content-box;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: .5em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 8rem;
        transform: rotate(-<?php echo $grau ?>deg); }
      .quantidades:after {
        content: "<?php echo $qtv; ?>%";
        line-height: 13rem;
        background: linear-gradient(Transparent 50%, <?php echo $cordefundo; ?> 50%);
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-<?php echo $grau ?>deg);
        line-height: 13rem; }


    /*Aqui o posicionamento do gráfico na página */
    #content1{
        background: #e7eef5;
        margin-top: 37px; 
        margin-left:8px;
    }
```

Aqui o HTML:

```
 <article  id="content1">
    <div class="quantidades"></div>
    </article>
```

Comment: Tem coisa errada nesse CSS. Você não fechou a *tag* PHP antes de começar com os códigos CSS e isso gerará um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Ato falho Anderson. Editei a pergunta para retratar o código

Comment: Agora tem código PHP fora das *tags* PHP. Aliás, o PHP é realmente necessário para o problema da pergunta? Por quê não constrói um [mcve] colocando apenas o CSS gerado?

Comment: Também recomendo que ao trabalhar com css usando php, habilite short_open_tag no php.ini (caso não esteja habilitado), e trabalhe com <?= 'x' ?> em vez de <?php echo 'x' ?>

Comment: Posso estar errado pois sou leigo de PHP, mas acho que essa parte pode dar erro, não? `content: "<?php echo $qtv; ?>%";` Acho que esse PHP não funcionará dentro das aspas e pode gerar erro.